# Spring Boot System.GetProperty read value from weblogic arguments

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic, weblogic12c

Hi I have a spring application and I have a system.getproperty("xxx"); command.My app work in adminserver in weblogic and I added my property via admin console ( server-->configuration-->argument like -Dxxx=yyy

Also I restart my server and still I cant see my xxx property value?

Is there any missing point?

Comment: are you restarting with Node Manager?, system properties assigned in admin-console in different servers, these servers must start through Node Manager

Comment: I restart my computer and restart sh but still same situation

Comment: you need to add those properties to your sh startup script.

Comment: I understand you have added these system properties in the configuration/Remote start of the managed server. This option is only used by the Node Manager and when it does not use startup scripts to start managed servers.
You have to follow @devwebcl advice.

Comment: As I understand correctly we cant  set any custom argument to admin server ?Because for test purpose I start application on admin server and try to set argument to admin server but I cant see ?Am I right? @EmmanuelCollin

Comment: No. It is possible to set custom arguments to the admin server as well as managed servers.
If you start your server using script, set your custom properties in the bin/setUserOverrides.sh shell script.
If you start your server through the NodeManager without using scripts, set your custom properties in the admin console.